# SQL Server 2008 R2 login/password

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i recently installed SQL Server 2008 R2 management studio. When I try to login i select 'Database engine' as the server type, I'm not sure what server name I'm supposed to be using but I tried .\SQLEXPRESS and authentication is 'SQL server Authentication'. But as for login and password I don't have one. During the installation I was not prompted to provide a login/password. As with the 2005 server installation I could by selecting 'mixed'. So how do i login for the first time on SQL server 2008 if i dont know/have my login/password?

Comment: Try windows auth and using your credentials

Comment: tried that with .\SQLEXPRESS as server name - still not working

Comment: this is the error: http://i.imgur.com/eoXaeoI.png

Comment: have you just installed `SQL Server 2008 R2 management studio` or `Sql Server` itself ??? go to your windows `Services` and check there if you can find SqlServer there ???

Comment: wierd, neither are there..

Comment: not wierd at all I think you have just installed the SSMS `Sql Server Management Studio` which is client application used for connecting to sql server you need to download and install sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your comments its obvious that you have only installed sql server management studio and not `Sql Server` itself. you can download sql server from this link below

[Download Sql Server 2008 Express Edition.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=1695)

Comment: still getting the error after installing SQL server:http://i.imgur.com/L5h94dj.png

Comment: where it says server name you should use . `local\InstanceName` now instance name will be what ever you selected when you installed sql server, if you left it as default then default instance name in your case will be `localhost\sqlserver` or `localhost\sqlexpress`

Comment: for Authentication Section Select `Windows Authentication` you dont need to use `sa` account. if you are logged in on your machine as Administrator you will have Administrator rights in sql server as well

Comment: when you were installing what `Authentication Mode` did you select it should have given you two options, 1) Windows Authentication 2) Mixed Mode. which one did you select ??

Comment: i chose mixed /10char

Comment: i chose the default instance name and i tried the default ones you gave me but they didn't work. next to the sql service it says (MSSQLSERVER) i also tried that as the instance name and it didn't work

Comment: edit: i just tried using 'local' as the server name and it worked.

Comment: thats fine then, it means you can use both Windows and Sql Server Authentication Modes to connect to sql server. just use `localhost\SqlServer` in your Server Name section and or `localhost\InstanceName_You_Selected` and use `Windows Authentication` in your Authentication section.

Comment: Now execute this statement and get your instance name `SELECT @@SERVERNAME, @@SERVICENAME` and remember it next time :)

Comment: ya it was the MSSQLSERVER :D